# Find a given text position in PDF file

Tags: java, itext

I have a pdf file and I want to find the position / get the height and width of the text on it. So far I am only able to give the position manually by myself, ideally I want to get this position. Here is my code below:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("c:/users/qasimovn/desktop/0011E06210410008 __v3.pdf");

PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
    new FileOutputStream("c:/users/qasimovn/desktop/newSened.pdf"));

Image image = mage.getInstance("c:/users/qasimovn/desktop/imza.jpg");

for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {

    PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
    image.setAbsolutePosition(400 f, 50 f);
    content.addImage(image);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "find the text position"? 
What are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: Which itext version do you use? If it's 5.5.x, looking for the position of some text in the page content can be done using the itext parsing framework. If it's 2.1.x, that framework may not yet exist.

Comment: @CodeAddict
I want to find the position of any word I enter.
then I want to send the position I found into this method.

image.setAbsolutePosition(400f, 50f);

Answer (score 2):

TEXT 7 allows you to parse pdf files according to different strategies. Here is an example of how to find a TextRectangle using TextMarginFinder. The rest of the strategies are inherited from the EventListener.

```
    public static final String src
        = "./src/main/resources/pdfs/preface.pdf";
  
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
    TextMarginFinder strategy = new TextMarginFinder();
    PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        parser.processPageContent(pdfDoc.getPage(i));
        Rectangle textRectangle = strategy.getTextRectangle();
        float left = textRectangle.getLeft();
        float right = textRectangle.getRight();
        float width = textRectangle.getWidth();
      //float etc...
    }
    pdfDoc.close();
```